# Git Running SSH Under Different Port

Tags: linux, git, ssh

Our servers at work don't use Port 22 for SSH - they use a 4 digit Port.

Now when I try to use commands such as `git fetch`, `git pull` etc. It cannot connect because it's trying to connect using our 4 digit Port

```
[user@server]$ sudo git fetch --verbose
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 2222: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I tested this with the SSH command

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

and got the same result, that it couldn't connect. So I added a Host in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket.org
      Port 22
```

and the command connected! The `git` commands however, do not connect, and I am still getting the first errors.

My remotes are set up correctly as they're been used elsewhere,

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/repo.git (push)
```

and SSH keys are setup correctly.

Does anyone know how to get around this so I can use the `git` commands via SSH?

Appreciate any help given.

Chris

Comment: Why are you running your `git` commands as root (`sudo`) ? you should not need that : run a flat `git fetch --verbose`. This also would explain why this command does not use your user's ssh settings (it would use root's ... )

Answer (score -1):

Edit your ssh config file: `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host bitbucket.org
  Hostname altssh.bitbucket.org
  Port 443
```

Comment: Question already says "I added a Host in ~/.ssh/config"